# Nginx правило location

Tags: nginx, rewrite

Необходимо настроить ответ 200 для всех страниц содержащих в адресе $WEB. При этом самой директории $WEB На сервере нету.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    root /var/www/html/;
    index index.htm index.html;
    location /api {
        .......
    }
}
```

примеры страниц запроса

```
/$WEB/url/test1/index.html
/$WEB/url/test2/index.html
```

Comment: А что сервер должен вернуть кроме `200`?

Comment: В том то и дело что по этой переменной на смарт тв подгружаются свои файлы, но запрос дублируется к nginx.

Comment: Вы не ответили на вопрос. И вообще зачем 200 если и так работает?

Comment: Есть другие модели тв, где из-за ответа на этот запрос отдает 404 и телевизор пишет сервис недоступен

Comment: Ок. Но вы всё ещё не ответили на первый  вопрос.

Comment: можно любой пустой файл, в запросе с телевизора ожидается .js файл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
location ^~ /$WEB/ {
    return 200 "";
}
```

Comment: Если в конце url пусто http://local/test$WEB/url/, nginx нормально отвечает 200, но если указан конкретный файл, http://local/test$WEB/url/test.js, упорно отдается 404.

Comment: @drq12 поправил ответ. Видимо вы показали не весь конфиг